# Putting a particular sequence of sets in closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to use the following sequence of sets for a counterexample to a question (not homework):
$$I_1 = [0,1/2), \ I_2 = [1/2,1], \ I_3 = [0,1/3), \ I_4 = [1/3,2/3) , \ I_5 = [2/3,1], \ \dots$$
Where the next interval would be $[0,1/4)$. My problem is that I have no clue how to put this in a closed form. Is there any simple expression for $I_n$? Or perhaps an iterative definition? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a closed form?  Could you use double indexing, like $I_{jk}=[(k-1)/j,k/j)$ with $k\leq j$.  You might need one extra case when you're including $1$ (for the open/closed endpoints).

Comment: Damn. That'll do, actually. I really just wanted a way to write the sets so that the pattern is clear to the reader.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. I can set $I_{j,k} := [(k-1)/j , j/k)$ for $1 \leq k <j$, $I_{j,j} = [(j-1)/j , 1]$, and $j \geq 2$.